# `Package has no installation candidate` on Debian but not on Ubuntu

Tags: debian, apt, docker

I'm using Docker with the php-fpm image, which uses Debian Buster as its OS. I'm a bit confused as why these two packages: `php-smbclient` and `php7.3-sybase` are not able to be installed, as they are listed in the official repository. I'm running `apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y php-smbclient` so I don't think I'm doing anything wrong. However, I can still these packages on Ubuntu. I'm thinking of downloading the .deb and installing it manually if I have no other choice. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `7.2-debian-10-prod` tag, to get an image based on Debian 10 (Buster), everything works fine:

```
docker pull bitnami/php-fpm:7.2-debian-10-prod
```

The inside the container, run `apt update && apt install -y php-smbclient php-sybase`.